# Uiautomator bounds to coordinates using adb

Tags: java, android, adb, android-uiautomator

I have currently an issue i am using UIautomator to pull the xml file and i try to find a button by the text writen then try to stimulate the click using adb. But I am unable to make the right conversion of bounds to x and y coordinates.
This is the code i am using to grab the xml file.

```
adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml $TMPDIR
```

Here the is the code i am using to convert bounds to coordinates the text in the box is : Signaler.

```
coords=$(perl -ne 'printf "%d %d\n", ($1)/2, ($3)/2 if /text="Signaler"[^>]*bounds="\[(\d+),(\d+)\]\[(\d+),(\d+)\]"/' $TMPDIR/window_dump.xml)
```

What am I doing wrong Please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIAutomator tool to get the XY coordinates of the view.